# Unable to Locate element in salesforce using watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

Problem 1:
Input:

```
browser.span(:id => 'ProdSelectionPage_Fav:mainform:pbmain:pSecId:j_id90:txtQuoteDesc').when_present.exist?
```

Error:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/wait.rb:29:in `until': timed out after 60 seconds (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/element_extensions.rb:18:in `method_missing'
from C:/WebAutomation/Tests/sandbox/attach.rb:52:in `<main>'
```

Problem 2:
Input:

```
browser.frame.text_field(:id, /ProdSelectionPage_Fav:mainform:pbmain:pSecId:j_id90:txtQuoteDesc/).when_present.set'gautam raj'
```

Error:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/wait.rb:29:in `until': timed out after 60 seconds (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/element_extensions.rb:18:in `method_missing'
from C:/WebAutomation/Tests/sandbox/attach.rb:56:in `<main>'
```

---

Without 'when_present' and used 'sleep 30' before

Input:

```
browser.frame.text_field(:id, /ProdSelectionPage_Fav:mainform:pbmain:pSecId:j_id90:txtQuoteDesc/).set'gautam raj'
```

// tried 'name' instead of 'id' for input

Error:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:338:in `assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["frame", "iframe"]} (Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException)
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/frame.rb:21:in `document'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/frame.rb:52:in `__ole_inner_elements'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:204:in `each_element'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:229:in `each'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:217:in `locate'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/input_elements.rb:20:in `locate'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:335:in `assert_exists'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:484:in `perform_action'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/input_elements.rb:252:in `set'
from C:/WebAutomation/Tests/sandbox/attach.rb:56:in `<main>'
```

html code:

```
<input name="ProdSelectionPage_Fav:mainform:pbmain:pSecId:j_id90:txtQuoteDesc" id="ProdSelectionPage_Fav:mainform:pbmain:pSecId:j_id90:txtQuoteDesc" type="text" size="20" maxlength="35">
```

Comment: It would help if you give enough details to actually reproduce the problem. There are many reasons for why the element is not found. The most we can tell is that the element is not a span (which is why the first error occurs) and that there is no frame element.

Comment: I have tried by removing span and frame. The issue here is it could not either identify element.                                    browser.text_field(:id, /ProdSelectionPage_Fav:mainform:pbmain:pSecId:j_id90:txtQuoteDesc/).set'gautam raj'

Comment: @JustinKo @justin Ko I have tried by removing span and frame. The issue here is it could not either identify element.  CODE: browser.text_field(:id, /ProdSelectionPage_Fav:mainform:pbmain:pSecId:j_id90:txtQuoteDesc/).set'gautam raj' :.ERROR:C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/wait.rb:29:in `until': timed out after 60 seconds (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
 from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-classic-4.2.0/lib/watir-classic/element_extensions.rb:18:in `method_missing'
 from C:/WebAutomation/Tests/sandbox/attach.rb:55:in `<main>'

Comment: Are you sure that one line of HTML is enough to reproduce the problem? I created a page with just that one line of HTML and the Watir code you gave was able to input the text field.

Comment: Yes, this is working when we execute as a single piece of code, but not as whole. it is inconsistent on salesforce. Please suggest...thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have to work on extracting enough HTML/code such that you can share something that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the element you are trying to location never visible to watir.

So with `when_present`, it will fail with `Watir::Wait::TimeoutError` error. If you want to click/set the element not visible, it will fail with `Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException` error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was, when I move to next page, system is throwing error. So, I used below command when I want to move to next page

```
browser = Watir::Browser.attach(:url, //)
```

Now, it is working fine